# why key is not unique in MapReduce function?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

when I research in MapReduce functionality in Hadoop, it was very common sample is "WordCounting", and also this image is very usual to show steps of Map action and reduce:
https://wikis.nyu.edu/download/attachments/74681720/WordCount%20MapReduce%20Paradigm.PNG?version=1&modificationDate=1462902481180&api=v2
[image]

why in mapping section keys are not unique? for example car.

Comment: You want to parallelize it as much as possible. If you want to have `Car, 2` or `Car, (1, 1)`in mapping, you could not safely process each word on it own in parallel. And there would be little sense in it, as you will need to have the shuffle and reduce step anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**In Mapper** -

**Key** - offset of the text file.

**Value** - content in **text file.** (remember there are several file format with their own key value formation. **Text file take file offset as key and file content as value**)

In example of word count which you are assuming as key actually generated from value (content of file) in splitter and  mapper. In **Mapper key is file offset of text file which are unique for each Mapper.  Combiner and  Reducer work on generated key,value pair of Mapper and perform aggregate operations** and treat each word as unique in word count problem.